# Woocommerce product page image and thumnbails image

Tags: image, woocommerce, size, gallery

Is possibile set same size of every image in woocommerce products catalog?

If i upload image 500x900? or 1250x1000 etc.. there is about 3000 images with diferent size.

I see several option on woocommerce menu, but they have not been useful.

Use Flatsome theme.

this code fixed shop page :

```
.size-woocommerce_thumbnail  {
max-height: 280px!important;
width: auto!important;
}

.box-image {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 280px!important;
}

img.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:5px;
}
```

But, the problem is Product page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can also manage WooCommerce Settings.

Goto:

WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Display -> Product Images

Set the catalog images to 200px 200px and check hard crop option.

After saving these settings make sure you [regenerate thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to update the existing images according to the new settings.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/

Comment: Link no longer exists, and that WooCommerce settings page does not exist either.